# Fetch records from drupal database user table

Tags: mysql, drupal, phpmyadmin

I have been trying to prepare mysql query for fetch user records from drupal database,and i have prepared query as per below

In DB in user table there is user with created column which contain UNIX time stamps.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE  `created` BETWEEN 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('March 31 2017 00:00AM', '%M %d %Y %h:%i%p')) AND 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('March 31 2017 12:00PM', '%M %d %Y %h:%i%p'))
```

I have also tried below Query, but no result

```
SELECT users.name AS users_name, users.uid AS uid, users.mail AS users_mail, 
users.created AS users_created FROM users as users  WHERE 
users.created BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP( (  'Mar 31 2017 00:00:00' ) ) AND 
                      UNIX_TIMESTAMP( (  'April 1 2017 00:00:00' ) )
ORDER BY users_created ASC
```

While i run this query from mysql i am getting no result, while there are multiple records exist in DB.

Can any one let me know what is wrong in MySQL query?

Answer (score 0):

try with unix timestamp value before and check if you have results. Other way is to check if created unix timestamp are correct in databases.

check :

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE  `created` BETWEEN 1488322800 AND 1488323520
```

if you dont have results , back to simple check

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(created) FROM users
```

you can controles results to see if you should have match

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and below query working for me:

```
SELECT users.name AS users_name, users.uid AS uid, users.mail AS users_mail, users.created AS users_created
FROM users as users 
WHERE 
       users.created BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP( (  '2016-03-31 00:00:00' ) ) AND 
                              UNIX_TIMESTAMP( (  '2016-04-01 00:00:00' ) )
ORDER BY users_created ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Open queries are bad for Drupal

use drupal api

```
$start_time = '1403564400';
$end_time = '1403650800';
$query = db_select('users', 'u')
->fields('n', array('created'))
->condition('created', array($start_time, $end_time), 'BETWEEN');
$result = $query->execute();
$record = $result->fetchAll();
```

you have to convert time into seconds before

FOR DRUPAL 8

```
$connection = \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection();
$users = $connection->select('users', 'u')
    ->fields('u',['created'])
    ->condition('created', [$start_time, $end_time], 'BETWEEN');
$executed = $users->execute();
$results = $executed->fetchAllAssoc(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

HOPE THIS HELPS YOU